# Werkzeug test client and utf-8

Tags: flask, werkzeug, python-unicode

Here's the code. When I send both fields it fails.

```py
import unittest

class UnicodeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_unicode(self):
        from cStringIO import StringIO
        from flask import Flask, request

        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['TESTING'] = True

        @app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
        def test_view():
            print request.values, request.files
            return "OK"

        file = (StringIO("0" * 1000), "filename.txt")
        string = u"∆_∆"

        client = app.test_client(use_cookies=False)
        self.assertEquals(200, client.post('/', data={'file': file}).status_code)
        self.assertEquals(200, client.post('/', data={'string': string}).status_code)
        self.assertEquals(200, client.post('/', data={'file': file, 'string': string}).status_code)
```

On the last assert it fails with:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/tests/test_uni.py", line 108, in test_unicode
    self.assertEquals(200, client.post('/', data={'file': file, 'string': string}).status_code)
  File "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 771, in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 108, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 725, in open
    environ = args[0].get_environ()
  File "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 535, in get_environ
    stream_encode_multipart(values, charset=self.charset)
  File "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 104, in stream_encode_multipart
    write('\r\n\r\n' + value)
  File "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 71, in write
    write_binary(string.encode(charset))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It works fine when I'm sending both fields with the Postman (a Google Chrome extension).

Is it OK and should I wrap fields with unicode with base64 or something else? Or is it a bug in the werkzeug test client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like test client bug, I already have another bug with test client when direct request work fine, but test client has unexpected result.

For me in https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/test.py#L71 I have `string` type as `str`. For string only this method not called, for file only this method do not called with your string. You can try temporary update this method with next for python 2 only:

```
def write(string):
    if isinstance(string, str):
        write_binary(string)
    else:
        write_binary(string.encode(charset))
```

I created bug for your example: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/973.